How to remove "other features" and move the position of E[f(x)] value from SHAP waterfall plot?
I'm using the {shapviz} package and I would like to plot a waterfall plot with only 5 categories, but without the "other features" category (which refers to the sum of the other features). Also, I would like to change the position of E[f(x)] because it is on the x axis when I use 10 categories.
My code, so far, for 5 categories:
g <- sv_waterfall(
  shap, row_id = 25, 
  max_display = 5, fill_colors = c("#e0115f", "#0096ff"), annotation_size = 5
)
      
g$layers[[4]]$data[2, 4] <- 0.5

The result of this:

Any solution? Thank you in advance!

When you drop some of the features, either E(f(x)) or f(x) will be wrong, so maybe it is better to just remove it.
library(shapviz)

set.seed(1)
n <- 1000
p <- 10
X <- matrix(rnorm(n * p), ncol = p, dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("X", 1:p)))

dtrain <- xgboost::xgb.DMatrix(
  data.matrix(X), label = rnorm(n) + rowSums(X), nthread = 1
)
fit <- xgboost::xgb.train(data = dtrain, nrounds = 20, nthread = 1)
x <- shapviz(fit, X_pred = X)

id <- 25

# Or: top_5 <- names(sv_importance(x[id, ], kind = "no")[1:5])
bar_size <- abs(x[id, ]$S)
top_5 <- colnames(bar_size)[order(bar_size, decreasing = TRUE)][1:5]

sv_waterfall(
  x[id, top_5], 
  show_annotation = FALSE, 
  fill_colors = c("#e0115f", "#0096ff")
)



I got it. I thought that the value of f(x) didn't change just by hiding the sum of the other features (and not removing them from the analysis). Thanks, Michael!

Btw. nice color!
